# Is there a sandboxable compiled programming language simililar to lua

Tags: lua, scripting, add-on

I'm working on a crowd simulator. The idea is people walking around a city in 2D. Think gray rectangles for the buildings and colored dots for the people. Now I want these people to be programmable by other people, without giving them access to the core back end.
I also don't want them to be able to use anything other than the methods I provide for them. Meaning no file access, internet access, RNG, nothing.
They will receive get events like "You have just been instructed to go to X" or "You have arrived at P" and such.
The script should then allow them to do things like move_forward or how_many_people_are_in_front_of me and such.
Now I have found out that Lua and python are both thousands of times slower than compiled languages (I figured it would be in order of magnitude of 10s times slower), which is way to slow for my simulation.
So heres my question: Is there a programming language that is FOSS, allows me to restrict system access (sandboxing) the entire language to limit the amount of information the script has by only allowing it to use my provided functions, that is reasonably fast, something like <10x slower than Java, where I can send events to objects inside that language with which I can load in new Classes/Objects on the fly.

Comment: "*I have found out that Lua and python are both thousands of times slower than compiled languages*" Really? Have you profiled some prospective scripts, or are you going off of other peoples' numbers? Have you tried LuaJIT?

Comment: Also, the performance of the languages is only important relative to how important the processing in those languages is to your overall program's performance. For example, if a script basically calls a few functions of yours, makes a conditional decision based on a return value, and that's it, then odds are good the performance of that code will be based on the functions *you provide*, not the script that issued those calls.

Comment: Most of the time it will be running script code since it is the peoples intelligence. heres what I used. https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/fastest/python3-gcc.html 1000 of times may be worst case, but I find 100x slower unacceptable aswell.

Comment: "*Most of the time it will be running script code since it is the peoples intelligence.*" Don't be so sure about that. Even if a script is long, it is entirely possible that the majority of the time is not spent in the scripting language itself. I imagine the execution of the call to `how_many_people_are_in_front_of` is going to take *far longer* to compute than whatever the script does to use the return value. Always benchmark your specific use case for yourself; canned benchmarks are not useful for your specific use case.

Comment: Hmm ok. Although all that event would do is create a 2D triangle that represents a persons vision and simply counts how many people he would see.

Comment: You would definitely create a native function that will access your world's database/model to count the number of people within that region. The speed of Lua is irrelevant then. You will not want to expose it all to Lua and then count it all on Lua side.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you think that if there was a scripting language faster than lua and python, then it'd be talked about at least as much as they are?

The speed of a scripting language is rather vague term. Scripting languages essentially are converted to a series of calls to functions written in fast compiled languages. But the functions are usually written to be general with lots of checks and fail-safes, rather than to be fast. For some problems, not a lot of redundant actions stacks up and the script translation results in essentially same machine code as the compiled program would have. For other problems, a person, knowledgeable about the language, might coerce it to translate to essentially same machine code. For other problems the price of convenience stay forever with the script.

If you look at the timings of [benchmark tasks](https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/fastest/python3-gcc.html), you'll find that there's no consistent winner across them. For one task the language is fastest, for the other it is way behind.

It would make sense to gauge language speed at your task by looking at similar tasks in benchmarks. So, which of those problem maps the closest to yours? My guess would be: none.

---

Now, onto the question of user programs inside your program.

That's how script languages came to existence in the first place. You can read up on why such a language may be slow for example in SICP.

If you evaluate what you expect people to write in their programs, you might decide, that you don't need to give them whole programming language. Then you may give them a simple set of instructions they can use to describe a few branching decisions and value lookups. Then your own very performant program will construct an object that encompasses the described logic. This tric is described [here](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/bytecode.html) and [there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_pattern).

However if you keep adding more and more complex commands for users to invoke, you'll just end up inventing your [own language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenspun%27s_tenth_rule). At that point you'll likely wish you'd went with Lua from the very beginning.

That being said, I don't think the snippet below will run significantly different in compiled code, your own interpreter object, or any embedded scripting language:

```
if event = "You have just been instructed to go to X":
    set_front_of_me(X) # call your function
    n = how_many_people_are_in_front_of_me() #call to your function
    if n > 3:
        move_to_side() #call to function provided by you
    else:
        move_forward() #call to function provided by you
```

Now, if the users would need to do complex computer-sciency stuff, solve np-problems, do machine learning or other matrix multiplications, then yes, that would be slow, provided someone would actually trouble themselves with implementing that.

If you get to that point, it seem that there are at least some possibilities to sandbox the compiled [dlls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/misc/how-to-run-partially-trusted-code-in-a-sandbox) (at least in some languages). Or you could do compilation of users' code yourself to control the functionality they invoke and then plug it in as a library.

Comment: I didn't say anything about a scripting language. I said I wanted a COMPILED language.

Comment: Python can be compiled.

Comment: >> If you look at the timings of benchmark tasks, you'll find that there's no consistent winner across them. For one task the language is fastest, for the other it is way behind. << The URL you provide shows Python always slower.

Comment: That is not url I provide, it is given by the asker. You can view per task scores, sometimes the winner is [Rust](https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/performance/nbody.html)  othertimes its [C++](https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/performance/revcomp.html). You can view  [problem statements](https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/description/knucleotide.html#knucleotide). The takeaway is that those results are mostly relevant to particular peculiar task formulation.

Comment: The takeway is that the OP was not comparing Rust vs C++ !

Comment: The op was linking that benchmark as a reliable prediction of unspecified programming language performance on an unspecified programming task. It is not. If actually follow the link, you'll find many more pairs of languages that swap positions depending on the problem. It is true, that  C++ outperforms, python and many others, it is expected, considering what python and many other languages are. By how much would c++ outperform other languages in a generic task is not something that can be extrapolated from the benchmark's set of task.